# Geometric representation of $2z^2 - \bar{z}^2 = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have tried to put $z = x + iy$ and $\bar z = x - iy$ but one $i$ still remains in the equation and to get rid of it, I have to square the whole thing again which makes it a $4^{th}$ degree polynomial and I'm feeling that this isn't right. Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Hint : $\mathrm{Im}(2z^2-\bar z^2)=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As given, put $z=x+iy,$ where  $x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$ So, we have that $\bar{z}=x-iy.$ Putting these values in the given equation, we have that $2(x+iy)^2-(x-iy)=1.$ On expanding and simplifying, we get $x^2-y^2+6xyi=1.$
Equating the real and imaginary parts, we have that $x^2-y^2=1$ and $xy=0.$
[image]

The geometric description includes the coordinates axes(both x-axis and y-axis) and the hyperbola given by  $x^2-y^2=1,$ as shown in the figure below. Since, both equations must be satisfied simultaneously, we need $z=\pm1.$ This is clearly seen as solution of the two curves plotted.

Answer (score 4):

Since$$2(x+yi)^2-(x-yi)^2=x^2-y^2+6xyi,$$you have$$2(x+yi)^2-(x-yi)^2=1\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x^2-y^2=1\\6xy=0.\end{array}\right.$$But $6xy=0\iff x=0$ or $y=0$. If $x=0$, the first equation becomes $-y^2=1$, which has no real solutions. And if $y=0$, the first equation becomes $x^2=1$, whose solutions are $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Therefore,$$2z^2-\overline z^2=1\iff z=\pm1.$$

Comment: Hi José! Don't you feel (like me) being the target of some serial downvoting these last 2 days?

Answer (score 3):

The given equation can be written as:
$$\bar z^2 = 2z^2 - 1 \tag{1}$$

Taking complex conjugates on both sides:
$$z^2 = 2 \bar z^2 - 1 \tag{2}$$

Eliminating $\,\bar z\,$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$
z^2 = 2 \bar z^2 - 1 = 2\left(2 z^2 - 1\right) - 1 \quad\iff\quad 3 z^2 = 3 \quad\iff\quad z^2 = 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Making $z = \rho e^{i\phi}$ we have

$$
2\rho^2e^{2i\phi}-\rho^2e^{-2i\phi}= 1
$$

or as $z\ne 0$

$$
e^{2i\phi}+2\sin(2\phi)=\frac{1}{\rho^2}=\cos(2\phi)+i\sin(2\phi)+2\sin(2\phi)
$$

then it follows that $\sin(2\phi) = 0\Rightarrow 2\phi = k\pi$, remaining then

$$
\cos(k\pi)=\frac{1}{\rho^2}\Rightarrow k = 0,2,4,\cdots
$$

and finally

$$
z = \pm 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

From the equation $1-z^2=z^2-\bar z^2$ we have
$$\arg(1-z)+\arg(1+z)=\arg (z-\bar z)+\arg(z+\bar z)=\frac\pi 2+k\pi.$$
Therefore, $z$ is on the unit circle.

On the other hand, since $|2z^2|=2$ and $|\bar z^2|=1$, and $2z^2-\bar z^2=1$,$z$ and $\bar z$ have the same argument. So, $z$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

$2z^2 -  \bar{z^2}=1 \Rightarrow z^2+ \left(z^2 - \bar{z^2}\right)=1$

Now since $z^2-\bar{z^2}$ is purely imaginary we have that $z^2=1$ and $z^2 = \bar{z^2}$

Hence $z^2=1 \Rightarrow z = \pm1$